# Windows is not resing on Social Engine

Tags: php, html, webforms, social-networking, socialengine

When I'm in the panel control(admin) I try no edit my HTML code, I click on edit and this appears:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dohIA.jpg

Obs: I can't modify anything because the block stays in the small size.
When I try in the demo  its appears normally like this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMZkC.jpg

I have tried other pcs and the result is the same. This happens every time it needs to load windows like those.
Can you guys please help with that??

Comment: probably better to ask socialengine support

Comment: they dont offer support for trial clients.

Comment: have you tried to inspect the element with chrome or something to make sure that the window actually has elements inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

It is the common SocialEngine problem which goes through all version I worked with (starting with 4.1.6).

You can enlarge the size of smoothbox frame using chrome inspector or other tool you prefer. But unfortunatly you should perform this operation every time you're editing an HTML block.